# For doesn't restart on dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, csv, for-loop

i need do read the rows of a dataframe but it seems to stop at the first row. I also tried with iterrows but the results are similar.

```
for i in range(1, 100):
        #for i, r in d.iterrows():
          if self.total_count >= 100:
              done = True
          else :
              done = False
          self.total_count += 1
          h = d.loc[i]
          print(h)
          if action == 0: 
              for index, row in df.iterrows():
                  if h['id'] == row['id']:
                      reward = 1
                      print("Equals")
                      
                  else:
                      reward = 0
                      self.miss_count += 1
                      
          elif action == 1: 
              num = random.randrange(1, len(df), 1)
              df = df.drop(df.index[[num]])
              df = df.append(h, ignore_index=True)
              reward = 0
              print(df)
          info = {}
          #M = self.df['id'].to_numpy()
          return df, reward, done, info
```

and the outpus is :

```
id      4z_3v0atqk0
size            131
Name: 1, dtype: object
Equals
id      4z_3v0atqk0
size            131
Name: 1, dtype: object
Equals
```

so the for doesn't iterate.
I hope someone can help me, thank you so much.

Comment: You have a `return` statement that runs at the end of the first iteration.

Comment: If you're talking about the outer for loop, it's because of the return statement that will leave the function after being called for the first time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing

```
return df, reward, done, info
```

inside the loop.
This breaks the loop on the very first iteration